# Django Database "Out of sync"

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm, uwsgi

I'm using Django 1.5 (with nginx and uwsgi) with a number of workers, but am running into a problem with getting all the workers to have access to the most up-to-date information.

Namely, when I create an object using django admin, it adds properly for that worker, but the other workers may not gain access to it for some time (longest I've noted is a whole day). So, I could create an object but it will only sometimes appear in the admin (and on the site). If I swap out to only a single worker, everything starts working as expected.

I suspect this is related to database transactions, as I believe each worker will have its own database cursor. I tried added `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` to my database configuration and `'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',` to my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, but the issue still occurs.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on, and how I can rectify the issue?

Edit:
Workers are uwsgi workers, starting using `exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`, where `/etc/uwsgi/vassals/mysite.ini` is available with the following (trimmed) content

```
[uwsgi]
workers=1
; [...]
```

Comment: Not without seeing some code, and a clearer explanation of what these workers are. How are they started? What do they do? Where do they run?

Comment: They are uwsgi workers. Started using upstart, uwsgi in emperor mode.

Comment: Right, so you're not talking about separate long-running tasks: these are just serving the actual site, yes? Now, you need to show some code for models that are exhibiting the problem. Since you mention day-long delays, it seems likely that you're doing some work at process startup that evaluates querysets and stores them globally, so the queryset is not re-evaluated until a new process starts up. But we can't help without seeing some code.

Comment: This seems to have resolved itself (as in I can no longer get this behavior to occur). I am, however, still cautious. Should the issue re-occur and I can figure out why I'll bring the solution back here. Thanks anyway, @Daniel Roseman